# adding a url in django-template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-login

i tried to add a url in django template which is supposedly to log out a user

```
<div><a href="{% url 'accounts.views.user_logout' %}">logout</a></div>
```

but it threw a `NoReverseMatch`

the template:

```
<header class="grid-header header">
    <div class='logo-text'>Nitro fleet</div>
    <div class="profile-detail">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <img class="profile-img" src="{{user.picture.url}}" />
        <div>
        <div>{{user.username}}</div>
        <div><a href="{% url 'accounts.views.user_logout' %}">logout</a></div>
        </div>
        {%endif%}
    </div>
</header>
```

the url of the app (accounts) that has the logout view:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
appname = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('register', views.register_view , name='user_register'),
    path('login', views.user_login , name='user_login'),
    path('logout', views.user_logout , name='user_logout'),
]
```

the view function:

```
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

the complete error log:

```
NoReverseMatch at /maintenance/
Reverse for 'accounts.views.user_logout' not found. 'accounts.views.user_logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/maintenance/
Django Version: 3.2.9
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'accounts.views.user_logout' not found. 'accounts.views.user_logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py, line 694, in _reverse_with_prefix
Python Executable:  C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\nitrofleet',
 'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Mon, 31 Jan 2022 20:43:51 +0000
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be simply `<a href="{% url 'user_logout' %}">logout</a>`?

Comment: @R.Uziel it actually was, thank you that's a great help. any idea why the way i used it didnt work though ? is it wrong all together ?

Comment: Yes.  The first part of the path is that actual path you'll see in the url in your browser, the view is where the logic is done that can then be used to render a template.  The name is the part that django uses to find the correct path.  That's the one you use in links, form actions in your template.  I'm glad it helped.

Comment: The answer from Razenstein is probably better since it takes into account what happens if you have the same name in two different apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the name of the view:
{% url 'accounts:user_logout' %}